# How to make the function inside another function on template for blaze template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I use meteor.js.

I installed i18n and arillo:flow-router-helpers packages.
I need to do like:

```
<a href="{{ pathFor i18n 'dictionary.update' }}">edit</a>
```

which means pathFor(i18n('dictonary.update')) in javascript.

How to do this on blaze template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parentheses to compose functions in blaze.

you can do this `{{pathFor (i18n 'dictionary.update') }}`

the parentheses `()` call the function `i18n` with the argument `dictionary.update`. Its kinda like [lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)), [the best programming language ever](https://xkcd.com/224/).

this would be equivalent to `pathFor( i18n('dictionary.update') );` if the functions where just in regular JS.

I hope that helps.